# Get all method calls

Tags: c#, vssdk

Let's say I have simple project

```
class Program : TestBase
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }

    public void Test()
    {
        AddItem(new Item());
        AddItem(new Item());
    }
}

public class Item { }

public class TestBase
{
    public virtual void AddItem(Item vertex) { }
}
```

How can I extract `AddItem(new Item());` using VSSDK? I want to know what parameters are passed to it and at what line it is in the text editor.

I tried looking for `CodeElement.Kind`, but unfortunately `vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunctionInvokeStmt` doesn't return anything. Is there any other way of extracting this information?

```
public static async Task InitializeAsync(AsyncPackage package)
{
    // ...
    _dte = (await package.GetServiceAsync(typeof(DTE))) as DTE2;

    await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(package.DisposalToken);
    var sandboxProject = _dte.Solution.Projects;

    var codeItems = new List<string>();

    if (!ThreadHelper.CheckAccess())
        return;

    foreach (Project project in sandboxProject)
    {
        var projectItems = GetProjectItemsRecursively(project.ProjectItems);
        foreach (ProjectItem projectItem in projectItems)
        {
            foreach (CodeElement element in projectItem.FileCodeModel.CodeElements)
            {
                codeItems.AddRange(GetItems(element).Select(codeItem => $"{codeItem.FullName} : {codeItem.Kind.ToString()}"));
            }
        }
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<CodeElement> GetItems(CodeElement items)
{
    var ret = new List<CodeElement>();
    if (items == null)
        return ret;

    foreach (CodeElement item in items.Children)
    {
        ret.Add(item);
        ret.AddRange(GetItems(item));
    }

    return ret;
}

private static List<ProjectItem> GetProjectItemsRecursively(ProjectItems items)
{
    var ret = new List<EnvDTE.ProjectItem>();
    if (items == null) return ret;
    foreach (ProjectItem item in items)
    {
        ret.Add(item);
        ret.AddRange(GetProjectItemsRecursively(item.ProjectItems));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Knowing the number of method parameters requires a parser.  So not the VSSDK, it doesn't have a parser.  A feature like syntax highlighting is based on lexical analysis.  Roslyn is the standard "parse C# code" solution, as long as you need only to analyze C# or VB.NET code anyway.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, my code returned parameter `args` for `static void Main(string[] args)`, so I assumed it would also be able to return method calls inside a method.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: @SimonMourier VS2019 Community

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With modern version of Visual Studio, if you're interested in the languages services, then you don't have to use DTE and the old FileCodeModel stuff, but you can leverage [The .NET Compiler Platform SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/) (aka Roslyn) which is the parsing backbone now.

So, first thing to do is add the latest [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces/) nuget package (roslyn for C#) and the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices/) nuget (Visual Studio Roslyn workspace) to your package project. Note you may have to fix the now-usual nuget mess...

Once this is done, you can write this kind of code instead of yours:

```
// get component model & Visual Studio Roslyn workspace
var componentModel = await package.GetServiceAsync<SComponentModel, IComponentModel>();
var workspace = componentModel.GetService<VisualStudioWorkspace>(); // requires "Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices" nuget package

// enum all the projects
foreach (var project in workspace.CurrentSolution.Projects)
{
    // enum all the documents in the project
    foreach (var doc in project.Documents)
    {
        // get the semantic model & syntax tree root
        var model = await doc.GetSemanticModelAsync();
        var root = await model.SyntaxTree.GetRootAsync();

        // find a class named "TestBase"
        // ClassDeclarationSyntax etc. requires "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" nuget package
        var myClass = root.DescendantNodes()
            .OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>()
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Identifier.Text == "TestBase");
        if (myClass != null)
        {
            // find a method named "AddItem"
            var myMethod = myClass.Members.Where(m => m.Kind() == SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration)
                .OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>()
                .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Identifier.Text == "AddItem");
            if (myMethod != null)
            {
                // get the list of method parameters
                var parameters = myMethod.ParameterList.Parameters;
                ...

                // get the start line for the method declaration
                var lineSpan = model.SyntaxTree.GetLineSpan(myMethod.Span);
                int startLine = lineSpan.StartLinePosition.Line;
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks lovely, I will give it a try once I get home.